# Completion before and after word vim

Tags: vim, completion

I added a dictionnary with this kind of words :

```
foo.bar
this.is.a.test
```

I did `:set iskeyword+=.` to have completion works despite dots :

When I type `fo<TAB>` --> `foo.bar`

But I would like to have also this kind of completion :

`test<TAB>` --> `this.is.a.test`

I mean, I won't type always the beginning of a word.

I hope I was clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just because I use qooxdoo framework (http://api.qooxdoo.org) and it's the syntax of every classes.

Comment: Ah, I understand that I completely misunderstood your use of the `this` keyword :-) Totally forgot about package names...

Answer (score 1):

With insert mode's `<c-x><c-p>` after `<c-p>`/`<c-n>` you can complete words that follow the previous completion. This assumes that the words appear before together. This means you do not need to add `.` to `'iskeyword'` (It is better that you don't!).

As for completing via the end of words that is probably best done via a custom completion as @Ingo Karkat suggests. However I personally have not come across a need for such a completion.

#### How to use `<c-x><c-p>` following `<c-p>`/`<c-n>`

- type out the first word or part of it. e.g `test` in the example
- hit `<c-p>` to start the completion and open the completion menu
- find the correct completion via `<c-n>` or `<c-p>` (optional)
- hit `<c-x><c-p>` to complete the next word e.g `.is` in the example
- find the correct completion via `<c-n>` or `<c-p>` (optional)
- repeat the `<c-x><c-p>` and `<c-p>`/`<c-n>` steps as needed

So all together: `test<c-p><c-x><c-p><c-x><c-p><c-x><c-p>` will yield `this.is.a.test`.

#### Conclusion

Using `<c-x><c-p>` is tricky to explain but much easier to understand after trying it a few times. Trust me it is worth it. You can also do similar tricks with whole line completion, i.e. `<c-x><c-l>`. Do yourself a favor and just read all of `:h ins-completion` you will be better for it.

#### Aside about using `<tab>` for completion

Vim offers various completion options. e.g whole line completion via `<c-x><c-l>`, tags: `<c-x><c-]>`, filename: `<c-x><c-f>`, and more. Often using a clever `<tab>` mapping or plugin like [SuperTab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) for completion hides these other completion modes by making them feel less familiar. Note: SuperTab is/was notorious for causing conflicts or bad behavior.

For more help see:

```
:h i_ctrl-x_ctrl-p
:h ins-completion
:h 'complete'
:h 'completeopt'
```

Comment: I don't think `<C-x><C-p>` works as you describe. The "previous" is just for the search direction (i.e. ordering of candidates), repeating it still completes _next_ matches. And it only considers words from the current buffer (not a dictionary).

Comment: @IngoKarkat You are correct this does not work w/ a dictionary and only works w/ the current buffer. However if you do have `this.is.a.test` already in the current buffer then `test<c-p><c-x><c-p><c-x><c-p><c-x><c-p>` can yield `this.is.a.test` (also assuming `set isk-=.`). I believe this is a reasonable native solution

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Sorry using `<c-x><c-p>` after `<c-p>` works w/ other buffers than just the current one. Just tried it. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I used isk+=. because I want this.is.a.test is considered as a single word and not four.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in completions always offer matches that *start* with the completion base. However, you can write a custom completion that implements different strategies.

If your dictionary is a loaded buffer (not the built-in dictionary completion `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K`), my [CompleteHelper plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) makes it easier to implement the extraction of matches. With it, the [BidiComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4658) offers something related: Completion of `this.is.a.test` when the cursor is to the *left* of `|test`. (I also have a MiddleEndComplete plugin in the works that may be close to what you want.)